# Weighted rotator table design

Tags: mysql

I am having a hard time with this very simple project. Maybe it's because it's Monday, I'm not sure.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id        |        weight        |    hits
------------------------------------------------
    1     |         4            |     0
    2     |         1            |     0
    3     |         2            |     0
```

Obviously, the hits column will increment by 1 each time that particular record is selected (We will run this update from within our PHP script).

How can I best retrieve these records by their weight?  What I mean is that if I ran my query 15 times, I would want the following IDs returned:

```
1
1
1
1
3
3
2
1
1
1
1
3
3
2
1
```

We have a simple formula in place that we got online that retrieves a random weighted result, but we aren't running the formula enough to statistically balance out the results, so instead we need to do a simple rotation as described above.

I know that this is a simple problem to solve, but I'm having a hard time coming up with the best way to do it today.

I hope I've been clear enough in my description of the problem.

Comment: Where you want run the query(ies)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused by your question?  We'll be running the queries from a PHP script. I just am having a hard time figuring out how best to essentially select one record at a time, sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something (it is Monday here too after all), can't you just sort by `hits / weight` and `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: For some reason, when I first started with this issue this morning, I got it in my head that that wouldn't work, but now looking at it again, it seems like it should work fine.  Why oh why did I spend all day staring at this?

I believe this is the best way to accomplish this and will satisfy our needs perfectly.

Comment: I was looking at this again. It won't generate a perfect sequence (like 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2), but in the end, the number of hits should be weighted properly.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's why I discounted it to begin with looking at it now. If I order by displays / weight ASC AND weight DESC, that gives a small priority to the higher weighted rows on the first few runs through. But on a weight=5 (ID=1), and two weight=1s (IDs=2,3), the sequence will be something like:

1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3

Which is close enough for our use.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE weight - hits > 0 ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

With the last result, run:

```
UPDATE tbl SET hits = hits + 1, total_hits = total_hits + 1 WHERE id = (THE RESULT);
```

Then run

```
SELECT (Sum(weight-hits)) FROM tbl
```

If result = 0

```
UPDATE tbl SET hits = 0
```

**EDIT:**

It's possible to make it with two queries:

```
$query="SELECT id FROM tbl, weight - hits  AS diff  WHERE weight - hits > 0 ORDER BY weight DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);

$i=0;
$id=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
$diff =0;
while ($i < $num) {
$diff= $diff + mysql_result($result,$i,"diff");
++$i;
}

if( $diff = 1 and $i = 1);
$query2="UPDATE tbl SET hits = 0, total_hits = total_hits + IF(id='$id',1,0)";
else{ 
$query2="UPDATE tbl SET hits = hits + 1, total_hits = total_hits + 1 WHERE id = '$id'";
}

mysql_query($query2);
```

Comment: `hits` is a TOTAL of the number of hits a record has received. So in my example queries above, after 15 runs of the query, ID #1 should have '9' in the hits column. #2 should have '2' and #3 should have '4'.

Comment: Create a extra column, like 'total_hits'

Comment: Told you this was a Monday problem ;)

This feels a bit hackish, but it's better than what I've come up with so thanks.  I'll wait a bit to see if anyone has any better ideas and then mark it solved.

Thanks for your help.